# Do checks like `hash?` in Racket support duck-typing?

Tags: racket, contract, duck-typing

I'm a Python programmer new to Racket...

I have seen some code like:

```lisp
(define table/c (and/c hash? (not/c immutable?)))
```

I understand this to be a use of Contracts, i.e.
https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fbase..rkt%29._and%2Fc%29%29

So it means that anywhere in this library which accepts a `table/c` arg, it should be an object which is a mutable hash-table.

My question is... does Racket have any support for duck-typing here (specifically to satisfy the contract of `hash?`)?

Say I wanted to replace the basic hash-table with something backed by a k/v store... Is there a 'hash-table' interface I could implement that would allow my store-backed custom object to pass a `hash?` contract check?

The docs for contracts and [this for the `hash?` check](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._hash%7E3f%29%29) didn't help me much.

Comment: You could probably do this with dictionaries, by implementing the `gen:dict` interface. However, `hash?` would not be true while `dict?` would pass

Comment: I specifically need a `hash?` check to pass for the lib I am working with. In Python I would be able to do some trick with abstract base classes to allow pretty much any type to pass an `isinstance` check as any other type. Failing that, is it possible to opt out of the contracts checking when I use the lib?

Comment: I had a look through the Racket src code and found this https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/a68c8eadc6fbcc901ef79342c07d80742e4c6ed7/racket/src/cs/rumble/hash.ss#L23 It looks promising: maybe I can make a "hash impersonator"? I'm a bit puzzled why I can only find it as a `.ss` file under the `cs/` folder, which sounds like something specific to Racket CS with the Chez backend.

Comment: Impersonator takes a concrete hash as an input though, so I don't think that's not what you want.

What's wrong with using `dict`? `hash` is not meant to be extensible, but `dict` is.

Comment: I want to pass my custom object to a method of someone else's library which defines the contract as `hash?`, so as I explained in the question I am trying to find a way to pass a `hash?` check

Comment: An impersonator for a concrete hash would be fine in my case I think, I really want a hash table that is like a "write-through cache" for something that persists to disk. So I could maybe build an impersonator of an actual concrete hash instance, where the key insert/update/delete operations are 'redirected' to my custom object methods... I will try this `impersonate-hash` method https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/chaperones.html?q=impersonator#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._impersonate-hash%29%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really want to use dictionaries for this, but if you're stuck with a library which wants `hash?` for contract checks then you can use impersonators.

Here's a function I wrote which tries to use a weak hash has a cache for some possibly-expensive computation represented by the (misnamed) `filler` function which will get called on a missing key.

I'm rather unsure about the semantics of this sort of thing (and I'm not an expert on any of this) but it works in practice.

```
(define (make-cache filler)
  (impersonate-hash
   (make-weak-hash '())
   (λ (ht key)
     ;; impersonate hash-ref by calling the filler
     (unless (hash-has-key? ht key)
       ;; I think this is safe as the key won't be dropped
       (hash-set! ht key (filler key)))
     (values key (λ (ht k v) v)))
   ;; Everything else is passed through
   (λ (ht k v)
     (values k v))
   (λ (ht k)
     k)
   (λ (ht k)
     k)))
```